# crontab sets up user variable, redirect output, and detect connetcted network

Tags: networking, cron, environment-variables, email

I have three problem, all of them are about crontab.

1. Can I access `$HOME` variable in crontab ? for example, use `$HOME` like this:
   `PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/scripts:$PATH` ? or `* * * * * echo "test" > $HOME/test.txt` ?
2. I want let crontab redirect normal `stdout` to `/dev/null`, but mail `stderr` to user. For example, when computer is **not** connected to network, then an entry in crontab like `* 2 * * * getmail -n -q ...` will return error, so crontab will send email to user with this error.
3. based on upper example, `getmail` will let crontab mail user when system is **not** connected to network, so I want a method to detect whether user is connected to network.

About this method of detecting, it should has bellowing:

1. fast
2. simple
3. easy to combine with other crontab jobs, (like use control: &&, ||, | etc)

Answer (score 3):

1. sure
2. `* 2 * * * getmail -n -q ... > /dev/null`

if you want redirect both stdout and stderr, then `... 2>&1 > /dev/null`

Comment: 2. I found a more simple one, &>/dev/null.

Comment: found in Google? had to do it before the stupid questions asked